# How to solve Apache-2.4 AH02026: Failed to acquire SSL session cache lock

Tags: apache-2.4, ubuntu-16.04, mod-ssl

I've just stood up a new AWS Ubuntu 16.04 server running Apache2.4 with PHP-FPM 5.6 and 7.1 available via different sockets. Everything is working great, but I'm getting the following errors in the Apache error log:

```
[Mon Jun 19 05:48:06.158306 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 18652:tid 140274127963904] (35)Resource deadlock avoided: AH02026: Failed to acquire SSL session cache lock
```

Now, I'm no server guru, that's why I'm here. I'm thinking it might be permissions on the ssl socket cache directory, but this is out of my comfort zone, so I need some expert advice / guidance.

`cd`ing to the Apache directory and `grep`ing the term `APACHE_RUN_DIR` gives the following:

```
foo@bar:/etc/apache2# grep -R "APACHE_RUN_DIR" ./
./mods-available/cgid.conf:ScriptSock ${APACHE_RUN_DIR}/cgisock
./mods-available/ssl.conf:      #SSLSessionCache                 dbm:${APACHE_RUN_DIR}/ssl_scache
./mods-available/ssl.conf:      SSLSessionCache         shmcb:${APACHE_RUN_DIR}/ssl_scache(512000)
./mods-enabled/ssl.conf:        #SSLSessionCache                 dbm:${APACHE_RUN_DIR}/ssl_scache
./mods-enabled/ssl.conf:        SSLSessionCache         shmcb:${APACHE_RUN_DIR}/ssl_scache(512000)
./envvars:export APACHE_RUN_DIR=/var/run/apache2$SUFFIX
```

So, we can see not only is mod_ssl available and enabled, it is also runnign with a configuration that states the `SSLSessionCache` is located at `${APACHE_RUN_DIR}/ssl_scache`, which equates to `/var/run/apache2/ssl_scache`.

I noticed that directory didn't exist, so I created it with `cd /var/run/apache2` followed by `mkdir ssl_scache`.  Running a `ls` on the directories gives the following:

```
foo@bar:/etc/apache2# ls -lsa /var/run/apache2/
total 4
0 drwxr-xr-x  3 root root   80 Jun 19 15:34 .
0 drwxr-xr-x 25 root root 1060 Jun 19 14:44 ..
4 -rw-r--r--  1 root root    6 Jun 19 15:46 apache2.pid
0 drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   40 Jun 19 15:34 ssl_scache
foo@bar:/etc/apache2# ls -lsa /var/run/apache2/ssl_scache/
total 0
0 drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 40 Jun 19 15:34 .
0 drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 80 Jun 19 15:34 ..
```

Also, we have this when using `ps aux` looking for apache:

```
foo@bar:/etc/apache2# ps aux | grep "apache"
root     16506  0.0  0.1 109328  9104 ?        Ss   Jun18   0:03 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
root     17387  0.0  0.0  22780  4808 pts/0    T    15:22   0:00 nano apache.error.log
www-data 18652  0.4  0.3 2044052 23388 ?       Sl   15:46   0:04 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 18720  0.4  0.3 2044728 24104 ?       Sl   15:48   0:03 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 18839  0.4  0.2 2043272 22480 ?       Sl   15:50   0:02 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
root     18913  0.0  0.0  12944   964 pts/0    S+   16:01   0:00 grep --color=auto apache
```

So I can see that the Apache process is running as user `www-data`.  I'm guessing maybe it can't access the folde `/var/run/apache2/ssl_scache`? But as I said, I'm no guru.

Is anyone able to shed some insight into why I keep getting `AH02026` errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I've found the root cause of the problem, and the solution. It turns out that there's a bug in Apache2.4 on Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04 (see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apache2/+bug/1565744).

By default this line in the file `/etc/apache2/apache.conf` is uncommented:

```
Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default
```

By rights, this configuration directive should cause the mutex file to use the default mechanism. If, in a vanilla installation of Apache2 you run the following command from the command prompt:

```
apache2ctl -t -D DUMP_RUN_CFG
```

...it should give the following output:

```
Mutex default: dir="/var/lock/apache2" mechanism=default
```

Instead, due to the bug, it produces this:

```
Mutex default: dir="/var/lock/apache2" mechanism=fcntl
```

There are two possible fixes:

1. The long fix is to use the fcntl mechanism instead of the default mechanism, which would include creating mutex files, giving them permissions, setting up sockets, monitoring them, and a whole heap of pain which I won't go into here (mostly because it's above my pay grade)
2. The easy fix is to comment out the mutex line in `/etc/apache2/apache.conf`, like so:

   `#Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default`

...which then results in the default mechanism being used by Apache.

Comment: Already commented this line in `apache.conf`. But not working.

Comment: Eventually you have other config files with the `Mutex` directive. In my case, the Mutex line was in `/etc/apache2/conf-available/mutex.conf`